# Upgrade Magento 2.1.3 to latest 2.1.7

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

My Magento version is 2.1.3 and i need to upgrade it to latest version which is currently 2.1.7

Should i upgrade to 2.1.7 directly or should i upgrade version by version like 2.1.3 to 2.1.4 then 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 likewise

will it create any errors if i directly upgrade to latest version?

Comment: you can upgrade it directly to 2.1.7, I recently upgrade my magento from 2.0.1 to 2.1.7 without any error.

Comment: Have you applied below any solutions or not?

Comment: Upgrade from Admin https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can directly upgrade your magento version from 2.1.3 to 2.1.7 using composer.

It will not create any error if you upgrade it correctly.

> The reason behind is If you have read release notes -
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html
>   Few releases have only security updates and few have only copyright
>   date update in all files(2.1.6). **so there is no major changes at
>   directories and files level**

Below are the commands how to upgrade it .

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update
(pass required update version number)

composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Same works for 2.1.8 too.

Comment: @Jai - Yes its standard method to upgrade version so it will works !!!

Comment: Yup. It helped me to upgrade to 2.1.8 without any issues so thanks and upvoted for same :)

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade your Magento version directly from 2.1.3 to 2.1.7 by below following command

> ```
> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update
> composer update
> ```

Remove below directory

> `/var/cache/* /var/page_cache/* /var/generation/*`

Run below commands

> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```

You can also check from here : [Devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: Error on front:Autoload error
Module 'Mageplaza_Core' from '/public_html/development/vendor/mageplaza/module-core' has been already defined in '/public_html/development/vendor/mageplaza/core-m2'.

......and Error in CLI: Warning: require(/public_html/development/vendor/composer/../mageplaza/core-m2/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in //public_html/development/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Answer (score 1):

you can directly upgrade your Magento version from 2.1.3 to 2.1.7 using composer.

try like this

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update
>
> composer update
>
> rm -rf var/di var/generation
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

for more reference

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upgrade from magento 2.1.3 to Magento 2.1.7.

There is no issue to directly upgrade from old to latest version.

Just edit your composer.json file,

```
"version": "2.1.3", To "version": "2.1.7",
```

and change other line,

```
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.3", To  "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.7",
```

Run command,

> composer update

After successfully Upgrade,

Run all magento command,

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Run upgrade and deploy command.

Clear cache.

Comment: It works but give error on front as follow:
Autoload error Module 'Mageplaza_Core' from '/public_html/development/vendor/mageplaza/module-core' has been already defined in '/public_html/development/vendor/mageplaza/core-m2'. ......and Error in CLI: Warning: require(/public_html/development/vendor/composer/../mageplaz‌​a/core-m2/registrati‌​on.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in //public_html/development/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run some commands to update your store to 2.1.7.

First, run this command:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.7 --no-update
```

Then update the composer

```
composer update
```

Now run these commands:

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**Note:** All these commands have to be run in the root directory of your store.